# What is the advantage of using C2DM over an application server?

Tags: android-c2dm, application-server

Why can't the application server send messages directly to the application? Why do you need the C2DM service in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

To send a message from the server side you have two possibilities:

1. The client *polls* for new messages in certain intervals. **Downside**: Not a real-time solution. If you poll too frequently it will drain battery, consume your quota (if you don't have an unlimited package). Generally you do a lot of unnecessary work and traffic as most polls will return no messages.
2. Stay connected all the time. **Downside**: hard to deliver technically as phones can close connections when going to sleep mode. (At least nothing guarantees that they won't). Also you are running a background application 24/7.

The current state of C2DM will give you:

1. The ability to get messages even when your application is *not running* as Android will start your application (the part of it you configured, not necessarily the whole UI) when a message arrives.
2. A central, shared channel to deliver such messages. If 10 applications need real-time notifications on your phone this is one single facility, not 10 applications running and polling in parallel.
3. The promise: As this is the sanctioned API by Google for push messaging you can expect it to be optimized in the future. One improvement can be carrier-level messaging to initiate a C2DM session. That would mean you can put 100% of the "smart" part of your phone asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Because the application can't (or isn't supposed to) act as a server.

If you would like to send messages to your app directly, then your application would need to have some sort of server listening in some port. This is bad because:

1. connections are usually firewalled, you cant just listen in some port,
2. your device can be turned off or without connectivity (then you app sever would need to retry),
3. the app server would need to know the address of your device,
4. app would need to be running (at least the server module) all the time, this isn't battery friendly.